# How much time script waiting response from server?

Tags: google-apps-script

My Google script, which I'm runnig from `script.google.com` invokes a PHP script on a remote server. This PHP script works for a few minutes, maybe more.

How much time can the Google script wait for a response from server?

Comment: note that a trivial google search for "apps script time limit" takes you to the linked answer and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detailhttps://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2329) advice from Google.

> We do not increase script execution times on a per-domain basis. There are ways for you to accomplish your use-case without any increases, however. Instead of trying to do everything in one script's execution time, use a sequence of script executions (using triggers) to process batches of the overall job. You can use ScriptDB or another persistent datastore to keep track of the documents processed, and each subsequent triggered execution can read from this and pick up processing where the previous execution left off.

Comment: i know, but i want know allowed time for waiting time in script.google.com. may a google not allowed a long time request

Comment: @LeoKomarov Just a note, ScriptDB has already Sunset, you can store in PropertiesService tough.

Comment: @Kriggs i don`t store data, i just created two triggers for my task, and running them one by one. First trigger send request to server, a php script does your job and saved data to file. Second trigger run after a hour and grab data from server.

Comment: this does not answer the question and mentions services thst no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

Better than "waiting" for the response, is making the PHP call a new function on GAS (sorta like a callback), to do this publish your GAS with the options "As me" and "Anyone, even anonymous". Then you can call the `/exec` link with Get/Post parameters and continue executing the function.

This is ofcourse if your editor on the PHP page.